# How to pass different data values to a same step from excel to a cucumber steps

Tags: excel, selenium, parameters, cucumber

I am trying to use the step "@when user enters the field value as "something"" for 10 Scenarios. each test case should pass different values. However steps cannot be duplicated in step defenition.

I have an excel hashmap Utility that can red the values from excel based on key word (Scenario name)

Now how can I get the Scenario name from feature file and get the data specific to each TC so that, value wrt to that particular TC will be updated and thus also avoiding duplication of the step

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking at a [Scenario outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline), which can help you data drive the same scenario.  One option can be that you put a step as below:

Scenario Outline: Test multiple inputs
Given some blah
When user enters the field value as "scenarioData""

```
Examples:
|scenarioData|
|data1|
|data2|
|data3|
```

Now in excel your key is data1, data2 and data3.  In the step definition

```
@When("user enters the field value as  {word}")
    public void printMeaning(String dataIdentifier) {
        //Read the excel, get the value for dataIdentifier
        //Input data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what the meaning of each different value is. If you don't then either you are

- repeating the same test (which is pointless) OR
- running tests that you don't understand (which isn't a good thing)

By giving each value a name which describes WHY you are testing it you should be able to write a better scenario. Instead of using a single step to enter any value, you use a specific step to enter specific values. Then you don't need any external storage of your values.

e.g.

You are testing passwords.

Your current approach puts lots of passwords in a file then has a single step input different passwords for different reasons.

My approach uses a single descriptive step for each password e.g.

```
When I input a valid password

When I input a password that is too short

When I input a password with a non UTF-8 character

When I input a password without a number

...
```

Now if you use these in several scenarios, you get simpler cukes that are of much higher quality in that they document WHY your application behaves the way it does e.g.

```
Scenario: Short password
  Given I am registering
  When I provide short password
  Then I should be told I need to provide a longer password
```

Step duplication is not important in Cucumber. The important thing is to write simple scenarios that clearly express behaviour in terms of WHAT it is, and WHY its important, without getting into HOW its implemented.